# How to show PDF's hidden content?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am filling some pdf form on my Mac, and it shows everything fine on my machine.
But when I email it to other people, they need to click on the field to see what content is there.

Why does this happen? How can I make it not hidden?

Comment: That sounds very much like missing appearance streams. Either the recipients of your mails use PDF viewers that cannot create missing form fields appearances or your PDF doesn't properly declare that appearances have to be created.

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF?